# Creating Raster ASCII file with `nlayar` and `layer_span` in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, ascii

Is it possible to create this ASCII file with `nlayar` and `layer_span` in ArcMap 10.2?

[image]

Comment: In all the years I have used ASCII raster format I have never seen those keywords, what created this data? Those keywords don't seem to be part of the ASCII raster format as described [here](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000421.shtml) so very unlikely ArcMap could create them.

Comment: You can do just about anything with Python, but you'd need to rewrite the file with the extra header information, calculated from unknown sources, in order to use ArcGIS to generate that file.